# How to extract time after a particular time and before another time in R?

Tags: r

My question might have been asked before. I searched, but I could not find. Thanks for your answer or referring to a previous post. I have two datasets. My datasets (DF1 and DF2) include Date, Time, and Value of my desirable variables (V1 and V2). Both Date and Time columns are of factor class. Here is my DF1 including V1:

```
#DF1
Date        Time         V1
6/2/2019  0:00:00        0
6/2/2019  0:01:00        24
.
..
6/2/2019  23:59:00       56
6/3/2019  0:00:00        78
6/3/2019  0:01:00        24
.
..
6/3/2019  23:59:00       32
6/4/2019  0:00:00        14
6/4/2019  0:01:00        62
.
..
6/4/2019  23:59:00       103
```

Then, here is my data (DF2), which includes variable 2 (V2).

```
#DF2
Date        Time         V2    
6/2/2019  0:00:00        2
6/2/2019  0:01:00        33
.
..
6/2/2019  23:59:00       12
6/3/2019  0:00:00        14
6/3/2019  0:01:00        56
.
..
6/3/2019  23:59:00       67
6/4/2019  0:00:00        94
6/4/2019  0:01:00        43
.
..
6/4/2019  23:59:00       156
```

First, I have to combine these two datasets based on a DateTime variable (which is the combination of Date and Time). So, I used the following code.

```
# I used the following to change the date class for DF1 and DF2.
DF1$Date <- as.Date(DF1$Date , "%d/%m/%Y")
DF2$Date <- as.Date(DF2$Date , "%d/%m/%Y")

#Then, I merged Date and Time in each dataset in a variable called "Datetime"
DF1$Datetime <- paste(DF1$Date , DF1$Time)
DF2$Datetime <- paste(DF2$Date , DF2$Time)

#Then, I changed the type of Datetime variable as follows:
DF1$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(DF1$Datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
DF2$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(DF2$Datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

#After that, I merged the datasets DF1 and DF2 by Datetime variable:
My_DF <- merge(DF1, DF2, by = "Datetime")
```

Now, what I need is to extract the subset of My_DF with the times (records) after "9:00:00" and before "22:00:00". For example, the output should include but not limited to all the 9:01:00 records for the seven days in my data. So, I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
New_DF <- subset(My_DF, My_DF$Time > "09:00:00" & My_DF$Time < "22:00:00")
```

The New_DF (my desirable output) should be as:

```
Date        Time         V1         V2    
6/2/2019  9:01:00        ..         ..
6/3/2019  9:01:00        ..         ..
6/4/2019  9:01:00        ..         ..
6/2/2019  9:02:00        ..         ..
6/3/2019  9:02:00        ..         ..
6/4/2019  9:02:00        ..         ..
..
6/2/2019  21:59:00       ..         ..
6/3/2019  21:59:00       ..         ..
6/3/2019  21:59:00       ..         ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it.  Had to create some data since it was not supplied

```
> # create data as factors
> dates <- as.factor(paste0('6/', 2:8, '/2019'))
> times <- as.factor(format(as.POSIXct(seq(0, 86400-60, by = 60), 
+                            origin = '1970-1-1',
+                            tz = 'UTC'), 
+                 format = '%H:%M:%S')
+ )
> 
> # create data.frame (tibble)
> tib <- tibble(date = rep(dates, each = 1440),
+               time = rep(times, times = 7)
+ )
> 
> # select data after converting factors to characters
> # (try to avoid the use of factors except for categorical data)
> sel <- filter(tib,
+               as.character(time) >= '10:00:00' &
+                 as.character(time) <= '22:00:00'
+ )
> 
> glimpse(tib)
Observations: 10,080
Variables: 2
$ date <fct> 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6...
$ time <fct> 00:00:00, 00:01:00, 00:02:00, 00:03:00, 00:04:00, 00:05:00, 00:06:00, 00:07:00, 00:08:00, 0...
> glimpse(sel)
Observations: 5,047
Variables: 2
$ date <fct> 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/2019, 6/2/201...
$ time <fct> 10:00:00, 10:01:00, 10:02:00, 10:03:00, 10:04:00, 10:05:00, 10:06:00, 10:07:00, 10:08:00, 10:09:00, 10:10:0...
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subset the data based on hour of the day :

```
#merge two datasets
New_DF <- merge(transform(df1, 
                datetime = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), format = "%d/%m/%Y %T")), 
                transform(df2, 
                datetime = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), format = "%d/%m/%Y %T")), 
                by = "datetime")
#Select relevant columns
New_DF <- New_DF[c("datetime", "V1", "V2")]
#Extract hour of the day
New_DF$hour <- as.integer(format(New_DF$datetime, "%H"))
#Subset the data based on hour
New_DF[New_DF$hour >= 9 & New_DF$hour < 22, ]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse` and `lubridate`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

inner_join(df1 %>%
            unite(Datetime, Date, Time, sep = " ") %>%
            mutate(Datetime = mdy_hms(Datetime)), 
           df2 %>%
            unite(Datetime, Date, Time, sep = " ") %>%
            mutate(Datetime = mdy_hms(Datetime)), by = "Datetime") %>%
 filter(hour(Datetime) >= 9 & hour(Datetime) < 22)
```